# Special characters other than delimiter in DelimitedLineTokenizer of FlatFileItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to read unl file in Spring batch.
Use FlatFileItemReader and delimiter is "|".

001-A472468827" |N|100| The delimiter does not work when encountering this data.
Data cannot be divided by the delimiter if it contains " and spaces or if it contains the @ character.
quoteCharacter doesn't seem to work.
In this situation, is there a way to import special characters such as " and @ as they are?

```
@Bean
  @StepScope
  public FlatFileItemReader unlFileReader() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<ExampleDTO>()
        .name("unlFileReader")
        /*.encoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())*/
        .resource(fileService.inputFileResource(UNZIP_PATH + "example.unl"))
        .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>())
        .targetType(ExampleDTO.class)
        .delimited().delimiter("|")
        .quoteCharacter('@')
        .quoteCharacter('"')
        .quoteCharacter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
        .includedFields(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141
        )
        .names(ExampleDTO.getFieldNameArrays())
        .build();
  }
```

In this situation, is there a way to import special characters such as " and @ as they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `quoteCharacter()` several times, note that this overrides the previous value and does not add the quote character to a list of quote characters. Only one quote character will be used (the last one added if you chain such calls).

> Data cannot be divided by the delimiter if it contains " and spaces or if it contains the @ character

This is because `"` is the default quote character. If the input contains a single `"`, you need to specify another delimiter (otherwise Spring Batch considers that as a "bug" in your data, which is true as the field is not correctly quoted). Here is a quick test that passes:

```
@Test
void testPipeDelimiter() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
    tokenizer.setQuoteCharacter(' ');
    String s = "001-A472468827\"|N|100|";
    FieldSet fieldSet = tokenizer.tokenize(s);
    Assertions.assertEquals("001-A472468827\"", fieldSet.readString(0));
    Assertions.assertEquals("N", fieldSet.readString(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals("100", fieldSet.readString(2));
}
```

This test shows that the `"` is part of the first field. The same test passes with a `@` in the input:

```
@Test
void testPipeDelimiter() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
    tokenizer.setQuoteCharacter(' ');
    String s = "001-A472468827@|N|100|";
    FieldSet fieldSet = tokenizer.tokenize(s);
    Assertions.assertEquals("001-A472468827@", fieldSet.readString(0));
    Assertions.assertEquals("N", fieldSet.readString(1));
    Assertions.assertEquals("100", fieldSet.readString(2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. The test code you wrote was also very helpful. I used .quoteCharacter('^'). So far I've been understanding the quoteCharacter option in reverse... Thank you so much for your kind reply!